# After using PdfStamper my custom fonts are replaced to Arial

Tags: c#, pdf, fonts, pdf-generation, itext

I have an app in C# with itextsharp that gets some PDF templates, fill some fields and export a flattened version.
Those PDF templates have some custom fonts, one font that I'm using it's DINPro-Regular.otf but after I replace the text and save it my font is being replaced to an Arial font.

I've read other threads but I couldn't find something that solve my case..

My code is:

```
    // Open existing PDF
    var pdfReader = new PdfReader(existingFileStream);

    // PdfStamper, which will create
    var stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, newFileStream);

    var form = stamper.AcroFields;

    // Set some info 
    form.SetField("part_number", part.PartNumber.ToUpper());
    ...

    // "Flatten" the form so it wont be editable/usable anymore
    stamper.FormFlattening = true;

    stamper.Close();
    pdfReader.Close();
```

I've tried to add those lines as well but didn't make any difference:

```
    form.GenerateAppearances = false;
    stamper.FreeTextFlattening = true;
```

[Original PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7dq424jfx1c9by6/Payen_gasket.pdf?dl=0)

[Generated PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gtk7az99qyagxm7/Bulletin.pdf?dl=0)

So if anyone had a similar problem or have a clue how to solve it will be very appreciated.

Comment: I've looked at your original PDF and as far as I can see, the font `/DINPro-Regular` is stored in your document, but I didn't find any complete `/Widths` array. In other words: the PDF doesn't contain sufficient data regarding the font for iTextSharp to be able to use that font.

Comment: Furthermore the default resource dictionary only knows the fonts **ZaDB** and **Helv**, not **DINPro-Regular**. But the spec says *the specified* font *value shall match
a resource name in the **Font** entry of the default resource dictionary (referenced from the **DR** entry of the
interactive form dictionary.*